# Cannot use Inline keyboard and parse mode together in node js telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, node-telegram-bot-api

Hey Guys I was making an telegram bot using nodejs telegram bot api when I cam across a problem .
I wanted to dispaly a html parsed message and an inline keyboard below it

```
bot.onText(/\/help/, async (msg) => {
  help_msg = `<b>This is the link for the advanced help</b>`;
  var adv_help = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      inline_keyboard: [
        [
          {
            text: "Advanced Help",
            url: "https://telegra.ph/Advanced-Help-for-Cloud-Torrenter-07-31",
          },
        ],
      ],
    }),
  };
  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, help_msg, { parse_mode: "HTML" }, adv_help);
});
```

But in this case the inline key board button wont appear at all only the parsed *help_msg* appears
[Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9HWh.png)

But if change the last line to

```
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, help_msg, adv_help ,{ parse_mode: "HTML" });
```

The unparsed *help_msg* that is the raw *help_msg* with  appears with the inline keyboard
[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiqM1.png)

can anyone suggest a method to get both the parsed text and button together

Answer (score 3):

I finaly got the answer

the command sintax is: bot.sendMessage(chatid, message, options)

object "reply_markup", stays within the options

like

```
const adv_help =  {
reply_markup: {
      inline_keyboard: [
        [
          {
            text: "Advanced Help",
            url: "https://telegra.ph/Advanced-Help-for-Cloud-Torrenter-07-31",
          }
        ],
      ],
    }, 
   parse_mode: 'HTML'
}

bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, `<b>This is the link for the advanced help</b>`,  adv_help)
```